# Complex filtering in Django

Tags: python, django, django-templates, django-views

I have a (simplified) Django model that resembles the following:

**models.py**

```
# python
class Hotel(models.Model):
     name = models.Charfield()

class RoomType(models.Model):
     hotel=models.ForeignKey(Hotel, related_name="roomtypes")
     price=models.IntegerField() # really  a currency field

class Room(models.Model):
     hotel = models.ForeignKey(Hotel)
     roomType = models.ForeignKey(RoomType, related_name="rooms")

class Reservation(models.Model):
     room = models.ForeignKey(Room)
     date = models.DateField()
```

So the hierarchy I need for my templates is `Hotel->RoomType->Room` where each has been filtered.

**views.py**

```
# only get available rooms that meet the user supplied criteria in q
q = Q() # complex query building omitted
rooms = Room.objects.filter(q) 

# only get roomtypes that have rooms meeting criteria in q
roomTypesValues = rooms.values_list('roomType', flat=True)
roomTypes = RoomType.objects.filter(pk__in=list(roomTypesValues))

# only get hotels that have rooms meeting criteria in q
hotelsValues = roomTypes.values_list('hotel', flat=True)
hotels = Hotel.objects.filter(pk__in=list(hotelsValues))

c=RequestContext(request, {'hotels': hotels})
```

Each of those queries work, in a way. I haven't figured out how I can use those in a template.

I'm trying to get something like this working (HTML simplified):

**template.html**

```
{% for hotel in hotels %}
<h1>{{hotel.name}}</h1>

   <ul>
   {% for roomtype in hotel.roomtypes %}
     <li>
       {{roomtype.name]}, {{roomtype.price}}
       {% for room in roomtype.rooms %}
            <!-- not really needed for this -->
       {% endfor %}
     </li>
   {% endfor %}
   </ul>
{% endfor %}
```

How can I pass the objects to the template so that I can process them in a way similar to the above?

Answer (score 0):

Your first snippet can be reduced to just this single call:

```
hotels = Hotel.objects.filter(roomtype__room=<whatever your criteria are>)
```

You can't do this query in the template, but you can pass that `hotels` queryset to the template for rendering there.

Comment: This results in a hotel (in hotels) for each room. If a hotel has 4 rooms meeting the criteria I get 4 copies of the hotel. And I can't seem to find which object to iterate to access the filtered RoomTypes in each hotel.